# UWP NavigationView Drop Shadow

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, navigationview

As you can see from the image, there is little shadow on the right of the `Pane` of `NavigationView`. I want to know where I can find the that style and How can I remove that style? I searched through the default style of `NavigationView` but I didn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There is a seemingly feasible way: you can find the control that generated the shadow in the style, and then remove the shadow according to this method: `Control.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` but this is too complicated, so it is not recommended. In addition, you can also try to let your custom titlebar to use this method:`titlebar.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` If they are both not successful, then we recommend that you can use the **ListView**(SplitView also can't) to customize a NavigationView.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT What is your `Control`? And titlebar does not have that shadow. Why are you doing the same thing to the titlebar?

Comment: The control refers to the one that generates the shadow in the style of the navigationView, you can try to find it in the style. And because the titlebar will mask the shadow, so I suggested that you could try to adjust the translation . These are just suggestions. If they are not successful, it seems that you can only use the listView to customize a navigationView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 May update SDK  there is property called "Shadow" you can modify from it

Comment: So what's the style of that shadow or how can I remove it?

Comment: I don't know what is the style of that shadow but you can go to properties menu in visual studio and modify on the shadow property of navigation view

Comment: this link give you some information about shadow that introduced with May update for windows 10 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/depth-shadow

Comment: Did you try it yourself? I have no idea how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Lone,

I had the same issue and I'm very glad I found the solution. After many hours of research, I discovered that the default behavior is that NavigationView Pane casts shadow on the ContentGrid.

That can easily be confirmed by commenting out the content grid - shadow no longer exists, because it no longer has a receiver.

In my case, NavigationView was implemented using a SplitView. That's why Shadow was bound to SplitView.Pane.

All I did is OnLoaded & OnCollapseButtonTapped I executed the following line:

```
 _rootSplitVIew.Pane.Translation = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

Shadow property works by elevating item on the Z axis, so setting it to 0 reverses the elevation and removes the shadow.

In your case you just need to find the proper element to execute it on (the element that has the Shadow).

In my case NavigationView was extended via TemplateControl. No reason this wouldn't work on a CodeBehind class too.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Your solution looks very much like the comment in my question. Although I have given up on removing the shadow, I am glad that you figured this out!

Comment: @SeakyLone I understand and agree, but I think my comment gives much more context to the solution.